# Aggregate functions in one SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My task is to use min, max and sum in one query. The main problem is that I have to add 3 more aggregates like sum only positive, sum only negative and distinct count.

I made a simple query:

```
select
   min(amount) as [min],
   max(amount) as [max],
   sum(amount) as [sum],
   sum(case when amount > 0 then amount else 0 end) as sum_pos,
   sum(case when amount < 0 then amount else 0 end) as sum_neg,
   count(distinct amount) as count_dist
from sometable
```

It gave me the expected results but I wonder if this task has a more professional approach?

Comment: Your query is fine. I doubt doing anything else is worth the complexity. Let's see if any answer pops up.

Comment: If your query gives the desired results, it is correct; SQL is a declarative language, the query optimizer decides how to go about accessing and returning your data. There's nothing wrong with your query, you hit the table only once and will require a single index or table scan. It's certainly possible to do worse.

Comment: What makes you think there is anything unprofessional about this? Its the perfect way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As many of the commenters have pointed out, this query satisfies the requirements as stated with the least amount of work to be performed by the query optimizer and database engine.

In a practical application, this query may over-simplify the data in the hypothetical `sometable`. Additional context could be added with a `GROUP BY` and displaying the aggregates on a per-entity/key basis, but that does not bear on the "professionalism" or functionality of the original question as scoped.